# Display spinner Content in EditText

Tags: android

I'll like to display the content of my spinner object in the editext but its only showing the content position i.e 0,1,2,3. Any idea how i can do that.
Here's my code

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
        int pos, long id) {
    parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);

    courseDay.setText(String.valueOf(pos));

}
```

this is the content of the spinner object

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="days_array">
        <item>Monday</item>
        <item>Tuesday</item>
        <item>Wednesday</item>
        <item>Thursday</item>
        <item>Friday</item>
        <item>Saturday</item>
        <item>Sunday</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this..

```
courseDay.setText(String.valueOf(pos));
```

to

```
courseDay.setText(yourspinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
```

Or

```
courseDay.setText(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
    private TextView courseDay;
    private Spinner spinner;
    private HashMap<String, String> questionMap;
    private String[] daysArray;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.arrayact);

        courseDay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.courseDay);
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        daysArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.days_array);

        // set your spinner adapter code here

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                courseDay.setText(daysArray[position]);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

    }
```